# EParseError Unrecognized parameter name "Type"on line 592 in Aeston

Tags: php, wamp, php-8

I updated WAMP to version 3.2.6, even installed Aestan version 3.2.4.2 separately (though the installer told me it was installed already). No errors when I start WAMP with a PHP version other than 8.1 but I do get [EParseError] Unrecognized parameter name "Type" on line 592 when starting Wampmanager using PHP 8.1. The services are started and phpinfo() tells me I am actually using PHP version 8.1.

PHP version 8 was installed using the WAMP installation utility.

Comment: Please post the code that is causing this error

Comment: There is no code executed. It happens when I manually start the Wampserver64 from the desktop.

Comment: The convention here is that if you solve the problem yourself, you should [post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing the question text. That makes it more obvious to future users that the question is not still waiting for an answer, and keeps the Question and Answer sections separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by (also) updating Apache to version 2.4.51